# Set all numbers greater than "X" bold

Tags: math-mode, bold

I am looking for a way to set automatically all numbers in mathmode bold (\mathbf) that are greater than a certain value. For example I set the new counter to 1000 in the preamble and every number greater or equal is set to bold in the pdf.

Comment: I think we need some context on how you would like the syntax to work, and under what circumstances you would use it.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a basic beginning to work from. You can make a command that tests any number against a maximum, which you define in another command.

If the numbers are in a `tabular` you can use the `collcell` package to apply the `\numtest` macro to each item automatically. See the second `tabular` in the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand{\setmaxnum}[1]{%
    \gdef\maxnum{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\numtest}[1]{%
    \ifnum#1 > \maxnum
        $\mathbf{#1}$%
    \else
        $#1$%
    \fi%
}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\numtest}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Max 10}

\setmaxnum{10}
\begin{tabular}{r}
\numtest{9}\\
\numtest{10}\\
\numtest{11}\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Max 1000}

\setmaxnum{1000}
\begin{tabular}{E}
500\\
1001\\
2000\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for.